# How to solve blank screen issue on Raspberry Pi GUI?

Tags: raspbian, linux, gui

It's my third day with my Raspberry Pi. I do know Linux. I am all good with using SSH with my Raspberry Pi but I do need a GUI sometimes. I tried installing vncserver, tightvncserver and now xrdp but nothing turned out to be right. 
I am even connected using my window's remote desktop connection but I see nothing on the screen of my Raspberry Pi. The whole screen is blank. Here are my commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Is there something I am missing? Is there anyone who can help me debug it?

Comment: RealVNC is preinstalled on Raspbian - just download the client on you Windows machine https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/ You may need to enable VNC with 'sudo raspi-config', under interfacing options.

Comment: I just installed the realvnc from raspi-config. It's connecting me but still i see a black blank screen.

https://imgur.com/a/FpA3F

Comment: Are you using realvnc viewer?

Comment: Right now i have this >>RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP which i downloaded from >>https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

But now i am downloading a raspbian which have the gui capability, from this link>>https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Once i install it, i will let you guys know. thanks

Comment: Is Raspbian set to boot to desktop or command line ? It needs to be Desktop ! (Raspbian Stretch with Desktop was correct, your 2nd link Raspbian Jessie is old)

Comment: I don;t know how to check that. Can you help?

Comment: 'sudo raspi-config' - boot options

Comment: Done. It installed "lightdm". Rebooted it. Now did the VNCviewer. The result is same. :(

Answer (score 1):

As CoderMike says,

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then services I think it is. Enable VNC. Use the RealVNC application or mobile app to connect.

Comment: I just installed the realvnc from raspi-config. It's connecting me but still i see a black blank screen.

https://imgur.com/a/FpA3F

Comment: Do the same on a spare SD that has a clean image. Also remove any other installed VNC servers.